# Yirmiyahu comforting the Jewish people

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, lamentations-eicha

I remember reading from [*Pesikta D'Rav Kahanna*](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_D'Rav_Kahanna.27.1?lang=bi) about Yirmiyahu comforting the Jewish people as they were being led out to exile (i.e. Bavel) in which they were suffering terribly. He told them I have to go back to the remainder that are in Eretz Yisrael. The Jews start to cry bitterly and say to Yirmiyahu, “Why do you have to leave us?” Yirmiyahu said, “If you would have only cried one time while you still in Eretz Yisrael, you wouldn’t have to cry so many tears now.”

Could someone help me locate where in this text I can find it?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to indicate why you think that such a discussion exists.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Why should he have to? I've reworded it to make it a bit more "question like" but I really don't understand why this was put on hold. :/

Comment: @ezra, the original question didn't make any sense. Why would anyone think that such a story might be in E"R such that people should exert effort trying to find where? Even the tiniest bit of history, such as the one you invented on Chiddushei's behalf, gives readers some assurance that the concept isn't a figment of the asker's invention, though it leaves us [without a starting point](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2100/). I'm hoping Chiddushei will edit in a sincere and helpful prompt; if s/he doesn't, and if you're comfortable with inventing his/her history, I'll re-open.

Comment: What did he say to comfort them?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's in  [Piska 27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesikta_D'Rav_Kahanna.27.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

**פסקא כ"ז אות י' (י')** א"ר ברכיה בשם ר' אבא בר כהנא בזכות ולקחתם לכם ביום הראשון אני ניגלה לכם ראשון ופורע לכם מן הראשון ובונה לכם את הראשון ומביא לכם את הראשון אני נגלה לכם ראשון זה הקב"ה דכת' אני י"י ראשון (ישעיה מ"א ד') ופורע לכם מן הראשון זה עשו הרשע דכת' ויצא הראשון אדמוני (בראשית כ"ה כ"ה) **ובונה לכם את הראשון דכת' כסא כבוד מרום מראשון מקום מקדשינו (ירמיהו י"ז י"ב) ומביא לכם את הראשון זה משיח** דכת' ביה ראשון לציון הנה הנם ולירושלים מבשר אתן (ישעיה מ"א כ"ז). חסלת.‏

... and I will rebuild the first temple - as per Yirmiyahu 17:12 - כִּסֵּ֣א כָב֔וֹד מָר֖וֹם מֵֽרִאשׁ֑וֹן מְק֖וֹם מִקְדָּשֵֽׁנוּ׃ - *O Throne of Glory, more exalted than the first, the place of our Temple* - and bring you Mashiach.

<sup>(This section of Yirmiyahu is part of the Haftara for Behar and/or Bechukotai, depending on one's Minhag.)</sup>